# Signing digital Signature in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, digital-signature

I am trying to create a SAML Response in coldfusion.I am using the following code to initialize the

```
signature = XMLSignatureClass.init(samlAssertionDocument, JavaCast("string",""), sigType, canonType);
```

but when i am trying to sign the signature with the key, obtained from keystore

```
signature.sign(key);
```

where

```
key = ks.getKey("#KEYSTORE_ALIAS#",keypw.toCharArray());
```

it is throwing the following exception:

> org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Could not find a resolver for URI 1100164796 and Base. 
>   The URl 1100164796 is the id of SAML Response.

I have searched google for last two days, but could not resolve the exception.

Comment: I just wrote some code to do this for a client.  I'm currently asking them if they mind if I share this with you.  If the say yes, I'll post it.  If nothing else, you might want to check out this URL: http://www.outsourcingi.com/art-271-Programming-With-the-Java-XML-Digital-Signature-API.html